# SMAC : how to zoom to/find a city?

Tags: alpha-centauri

Almost two decades now, and I never found this out.

Even [a hotkey FAQ](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/96102-sid-meiers-alpha-centauri/faqs/10170) doesn't help.

At the start of a turn, I get a message "something awful happened at/near <city name>.

I only ever play huge maps - how do I find  <city name>?

Comment: What's wrong with *Locate Base* `Ctrl+B`? Do you have any specific need? Do you need it just in time when the message is displayed? (that, indeed, is a problem)

Comment: D'oh!!! I have been playing almost two decades without being aware of that !!  And, not that you point it out, the FAQ which I reference tells me ms that. Feel free to post a answer, which I will accept while slinking off, with burning cheeks, into the night

Comment: Yes, the problem with the FAQ is that it uses "base" instead of "city", which can be slip off one's attention when searching for "city"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, when messages about events are displayed, there is no possibility to switch to the map, you can only view the base/city itself.

However, after the messages are shown, and the player makes their moves,  <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> invokes the *Locate Base* window.

One possible trick I personally like is renaming the bases (cities), prefixing it with continent name/number/id/whatever. This also helps alphabet-sorting the bases (cities) and navigatiion with <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrows between them, as shown in the screenshot (caveat: IIRC, the list was unsorted in SMAC and fixed only in SMAX).

[image: navigation buttons]